# What is the Object class in Java?

Tags: java

what is or what type is `private Object[] obj;`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`Object`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) is the ultimate ancestor of every class in the Java inheritance hierarchy.

From the API:

> Class `Object` is the root of the class hierarchy. Every class has `Object` as a superclass. All objects, including arrays, implement the methods of this class.

---

The declaration:

```
private Object[] obj;
```

declares a reference variable called `obj` for an array of `Object`s that `private` to the class that declared it. (Note that this doesn't *create* this array, only declares a variable capable of referencing it).

Comment: Bear in mind that an interface class doesn't have `Object` as a superclass.

Comment: Especially useful (for example) when a function needs to accept or return data that could be any of several types.  `public void foo(Object o)` can take an object of any class as an argument.  Presumably it would check the actual class (via `instanceof`) and act accordingly.

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman: In some sense, any interface "extends" Object. Any of the object methods can be invoked on an interface reference, without a need for casting.

Comment: @eaj: This is true, however it is worth noting that nowadays it is *usually* (though not necessarily always) the case that it would be better to write such a method/class using [Generics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java) which will do the same thing behind the scenes (through type erasure) but will have the compiler take care of some of the work for you.

Comment: @eag would o become any type I pass it? if i do foo(hello) would o turn into a String?

Comment: @user521180: No, while the (lowercase 'o') object instance is still a concrete instance of `String`, because within the method it is being referenced by a (capital 'o') `Object`, the compiler will only allow you to treat it as a (capital 'o') `Object`. Therefore you will need to use `instanceof` and [casting](http://www.programmersheaven.com/2/FAQ-JAVA-Type-Conversion-Casting) to turn it back into a string. (This is why using Generics is considered better if you have the option).

Comment: @Eyal Schneider, only implemented objects that inherits interfaces "extends Object". Adding to that, if you have `public void foo(AnInterface interface)`, you can't pass an interface directly but only its implemented subclass(es).

Comment: @user521180 No, it doesn't magically change. The argument `o` is still an Object, but `(o instanceof String)` will return true.  Then you can create a string variable `String s = (String) o;`  However, Reese Moore is correct that such things are better handled by generics.

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman: What do you mean by "pass an interface directly"? In your example, if x is a reference declared to be of type AnInterface, then the compiler WILL allow passing it as a parameter.

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman: you're flat out wrong about Object not being a supertype of interface types, i'm afraid. See section 4.10.2 of the Java Language Specification: *Given a type declaration for C [...] the direct supertypes [...] are all of [...] The type Object, if C is an interface type with no direct superinterfaces*.