# where to use object class in java?

Tags: java, object

I need to know about object class in java.here are few code I want to know why we use it and where use it

```
Object obj = arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
String str = obj.toString();
```

Comment: The questions does not clearly explain what you want to ask - can you be more explicit by giving some context to code you have put up?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377749/what-is-the-object-class-in-java?rq=1

Comment: i am asking for whey we use Object class like object obj = somemethods

Comment: Some methods (probably like your `getItemAtPosition`) can return all kinds of objects. If you can't know what object will be returned you should store result in some superclass of all possible results reference (in lot of cases it is Object)

Answer (score 2):

All "`Object`"'s inherit from `Object`, so basically any class in Java is of type `Object`, too.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html

Because of this, all classes implicitly have a few methods:

---

```
Method Summary

protected  Object   clone() 

 boolean    equals(Object obj) 

protected  void finalize() 

 Class  getClass() 

 int    hashCode() 

 void   notify() 

 void   notifyAll() 

 String toString() 

 void   wait() 

 void   wait(long timeout) 

 void   wait(long timeout, int nanos)
```

---

If necessary, you can override these methods to provide your own functionality.

For example, you can override the `toString` method to return a `String` that you feel sums up your particular instance of the class. Then, if you pass your `Object` to something like `System.out.println`, it will print what the `toString` method returns.

For more reading:

http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectclass.html

And here are some nice inheritance tutorials:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/inheritance.html

http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~lavender/courses/tutorial/java-06.pdf

Answer (score 1):

`Object` is super class of all class in Java. If there is possibility to return more than one type then Object will be returned (or) If API designed to be more generic then `Object` will be returned.

**How to use returned object?**

Based on context, you may need to cast (or) do `toString()` like you did.

Answer (score 1):

Generally `Object` should only be used when dealing with a collection of elements of disparate or unknown type. This then usually is followed by `instanceof` and cast statements. Many APIs return `Object` when then can provide disparate types and some of this is a holdover from Java 4 and older prior to generics. Whereever possible this should be replaces with generics.

**EDIT**

Couple basic rules, you should NEVER do the following: `Object ob = new Object();` There should never be a reason to instantiate `Object` in any code. The ONLY time `Ojbect` should be used is when the type is not know.

An example of how this has changes with generics is `Collections.max`. In java 4 this returned `Object` ([Java 4 Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max%28java.util.Collection%29)), In java 6 this has a version that returns a generic `T` ([Java 6 Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max%28java.util.Collection%29)).

java 4: `public static Object max(Collection coll)`

returns `Object` because at that time `Collection` was not generic

java 6: `public static <T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>> T max(Collection<? extends T> coll)`

returns `T` because post Java 5 `Collection` is generic.

Point being that in the past a lot of APIs returned `Object` simply because Java did not have generics. Now, in most cases, generics should be used but not all APIs have been updated. Going forward, you should always try to use generics instead of Object whereever possible.

Comment: can u explain in sample program or elaborate it

Answer (score 1):

The Object class is used when the specific class of a variable is not known. Object class is a parent to many classes (Integer, Sting, ...etc). In the case mentioned above, the `getItemAtPosition()` class returns an `Object` instance since a spinner for example can have many different Class types in it, so it returns a general one (Object), then you cast it to String (or other classes depending on the case) when the  target type is known in the context.